# How to get product Attribute options in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

How to get product Attribute options in Magento 2 in custom module, I need to sort them in alphabetical order.

I have a helper thats called from controller and my helper class is like this

```
<?php
namespace xxx;

class Admin extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_objectManager;
    protected $_logger;
    protected $directory_list;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directory_list)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_objectManager = $context->getObjectManager();
        $this->_logger = $context->getLogger();
        $this->directory_list = $directory_list;
    }


    /**
     * @param string $_attr_code
     * @param bool|false $is_numeric
     */
    public function sortAttributeFilterOptions($_attr_code = '', $is_numeric = false)
    {
        $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute')->setEntityTypeId(4);
        //$model->load($id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keep below code in your helper file to get all option of attribute in helper file,

```
class Admin extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,      
        \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface $eavAttributeRepository
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->eavAttributeRepository = $eavAttributeRepository;
    }
public function sortAttributeFilterOptions($_attr_code = '', $is_numeric = false){
    $attributes = $this->getEavObj($_attr_code);
    $options = $attributes->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);

    $allOptionIds = [];
    $optionLabel = [];
    foreach($options as $value){    
        $optionLabel[ $value['value'] ] = $value['label'];
        $allOptionIds[] = $value['value'];
    }
    print_r($optionLabel);
    return $optionLabel;              
}

public function getEavObj($attributeCode){
    $attribute = $this->eavAttributeRepository->get(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE,$attributeCode);
    return $attribute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can apply this code in you helper

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory;

class SomeClass
{
    public function __construct(CollectionFactory $attributeCollectionFactory)
    {
        $this->attributeCollectionFactory = $attributeCollectionFactory->create();
    }
    public fuction getAllOptions() {
      $attributes = $this->attributeCollectionFactory->getItems();
      foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        echo $attribute->getId();
        $optionsForSort = array();
        $options = $attribute->getOptions();
        foreach ($options as $option) {
          $optionsForSort[] = $option->getValue();
        }
/** your sort function */
       $this->sortAttributeFilterOptions($optionsForSort);
      }
    }
}
```